# Flutter bloc countdown millisecondes

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, flutter-bloc

I juste built a millisecondes countdown with **bloc**.
My **bloc** use a ticker that refresh my countdown **state** every 50ms.
But my **state** is recreated 20 Time by sec (1s/50ms)..

Will using **AnimationController** with **TickerProviderStateMixin** be a better option? And use my bloc only for storing the total Time to countdown. Or it is okay to emit state every 50ms (or less)

Comment: Totally depends on your use case. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a ring with multiple division around my countdown, I would like each division to fade in a counterclockwise direction. I already have painter which work if I give a value between 0 and 1. But it's my block that refreshes it every 50ms. I want it to be smoother as possible so I can reduce time again but I am afraid of a drop in performance. probably juste use animated controller for the ring and bloc refreshed every secondes for countdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first understand how a `Ticker` is different from a `Timer`.

`Timer` in Flutter is a general purpose timer where you can provide a `duration` after which the `Timer` fires. So it's meant for discrete timer events where the event will fire (possibly periodically) after the stipulated amount of time. So it can be used to periodically update a UI state in an interval and then rebuilding the whole UI tree by some means.

`Ticker` on the other hand is a UI specific timer that fires depending on the frame rate of the app. So if an app is capable of drawing 60 frames per second, the `Ticker` will fire 60 times a second. So this is more suitable for drawing twinned animation frames, drawing one frame on each screen refresh cycle. Thus `AnimationController` uses a `Ticker` (by means of `TickerProvider` and `TickerProviderMixin`) under the hood to smoothly twin from one UI state to another and drawing each intermediate frame on screen on every screen refresh cycle.

For discrete, perpetual animation (like drawing an analog clock where the second hand changes position each second) using a `Timer` instead of `Ticker` doesn't really imply any significant visual difference in the UI. However, in terms of performance and testing, a `Ticker` provides significant advantages over a `Timer`:

- Unlike `Timer`, `Ticker` mutes itself when the animation is not on screen, avoiding unnecessary rendering overhead. So if a new screen is presented over your clock screen `Ticker` will pause itself and subsequently the animation will also pause, avoiding unnecessary GPU rendering calls. The `Timer` however will continue to fire its events and will keep updating the clock UI in the background.
- With `Timer` you don't have control over refresh rate of your clock. So there can be frame drop if the previous screen update is underway and another timer events fires, requesting another update of the widget tree. This could give a visually jagged update in the UI.
- `Ticker` is optimized for testing. It can mocked, can be slowed down or fast forwarded for testing purpose.

And for smooth and continuous twinning transition `Timer` is almost always useless because you cannot control your drawing on every screen refresh cycle, simply because `Timer` doesn't give you any control over the frame rate of your app. On the contrary, since `Ticker` (and the `AnimationController`) only performs its drawing only based on screen refresh rate (frame rate), it is almost given that it is the only option when a twinning animation is necessary.

This [article](https://dash-overflow.net/articles/why_vsync/) nicely elaborates the use cases and differences that you might find useful if you are split between the approaches of using a `Timer` vs a `Ticker` (and `AnimationController` in general) for your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details! I understand better the difference